# Count columns with bash

Tags: bash

I need to find a way to count columns from a file OR stdin without using anything except *pure* bash. What I have so far...

```
input="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
rows=0
while read -r myLine
do
    a=($myLine)
    cols=(${#a[*]})
    rows=`expr $rows + 1`
done < $input

echo -e "$rows $cols"
```

I'm counting both rows and columns. Right now, my column count only works for files, not stdin.

Any advice?

Im running the following commands

```
echo -e "1\t2\n3\t4" > m1, ./matrix m1
echo -e "1\t2\n3\t4" | matrix
```

Comment: Just use `wc -lw < $input` to get all the stats you need in a single read operation. The word count divided by the number of lines is the column count.

Comment: What do you mean **pure bash**? You have `head` and `wc` in your code

Comment: I'm not allowed to use anything but bash shell scripting, so no awk, sed, tcl, bc, perl, & the python languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [number of tokens in bash variable](/questions/638802/number-of-tokens-in-bash-variable)

Comment: You really don't need `expr` if the current year begins with a 2. Bash has superior built-in arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise awk for this task, but if you need bash, you could use arrays:

```
let c=0
while read -r myLine; do 
  a=($myLine) 
  echo "Line $((++c)) has ${#a[*]} columns"
done < file
```

The array `a` is filled with the content of the line read by the `read` function.
The number of columns is the length of the array `a`.

Note this script assumes the input field separator `IFS` to be unset (and as a consequence to default to `<space><tab><newline>` for the `read` command).

Comment: The `echo` is superfluous; simply `a=($myLine)` will tokenize the string into the array. Also, you basically always want to use `read -r` unless you specifically require the legacy pre-POSIX behavior for backwards compatibility. (Still, if `myLine` contains a wildcard expression, it too will be expanded before evaluation.)

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the tips. I'm not sure to understand your remark related to `-r` option that is described in the man page as `Backslash does not act as an escape character. `

Comment: The original Bourne shell did funny things if you typed a backslash in `read`. The `-r` option turns that off.

Comment: Nice! thank you. Quick question. Is there any way to only do the column count of the first row?

Comment: @CoryAllen Yes just add an `if` statement to check the number of column `c` is 1.